# creating a ec2 instance in terraform using already created ppk key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

i am trying to create a Ec2 instance using terraform and trying to pass my key value.
i know i am missing something . Here is what i am trying :

```
resource "aws_instance" "packer-yellowpages" {

  ami = "ami-03ec9965cffdc1ef7"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  key_name = "yp-web-dev"
  tags ={
      Name  = "packer-yellowpages-tr"
  }
}
```

when i use my ssh client putty to log into the machine created i am getting a time out error .
i feel my terraform is not able to locate that key and i am missing this step while writing it .

Could any one help me with my issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed adding a security group to your EC2 instance.

You need to use the [vpc_security_group_ids](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#vpc_security_group_ids) attribute within your terraform document. By having no security group attached you will have no inbound access to the instance.

If you do not have an existing security group then you can create one in terraform using the [aws_security_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html) resource type.

Comment: If you add the `vpc_security_group_ids` attribute you should be able to copy the security group id(s) from your AWS console and append them like vpc_security_group_ids=["sg-abcdefg"]

Comment: i tired using it got this error " Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_security_group_ids": set of string required."

Comment: Did you use the square bracers around the security group?

Answer (score 0):

For `key_name = yp-web-dev` aws will add the corresponding public key to the instance default login account

For example debian based operating system the user login will be with `ubuntu` user.

If you want to ssh to the ec2 instance you will need the private key of `yp-web-dev`.

`ssh -i yp-web-dev.pem <username>@<ip>`

Of course you will need the port 22 open from your network to the VPC!

`telnet <ip> 22` to check if 22 is accessible from your network to the instance.